# Logstash input twitter authorized error

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, logstash

Any one have experience with below error ? Please help me

Logstash startup completed
exception=>Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, :backtrace=>["C:/logstash-1.5.1 ...

I'm using the below twitter config

```
input{
  twitter{
   consumer_key => ""
   consumer_secret => ""
   oauth_token => ""
   oauth_token_secret => ""
   keywords => [""]
   full_tweet => true
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => dots }
   elasticsearch {
     host => "localhost:9200"
   }
}
```

Comment: `Unauthorized` seems to imply that you don't have set the correct credentials. Feel free to share more info so it's easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks you @Val for your comment but I use same twitter apps details in php library I am able to fetch tweet

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace maybe?

Comment: Once again thank you check the full error ←[33m {:exception=>Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, :backtrace=>["C:/logstash-1.5.1
/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:2
1:in on_headers_complete'", "org/ruby_http_parser/RubyHttpParser.java:370:in<
<'", "C:/logstash-1.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/twitter-5.12.0/lib/twitter/

Comment: Please update your question with it, you have more room and it's more legible.